# How to get the difference between two rows in a sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

```
select distinct 
    shipperinf_coilid, max(PilerInf_CreateDate), max(ShipperInf_CreateDate)
from 
    tblL3SendProductionData
where 
    ShipperInf_CoilId not in (select distinct shipperinf_coilid 
                              from table_2 
                              where orderinf_ordernumber like 'b%') 
    and pilerinf_createdate != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
group by  
    shipperinf_coilid
order by 
    max(PilerInf_CreateDate)
```

The above query returns a list of coils and their start date and end date in a process. I'm trying to find a way to find the difference between the end date of a coil and the start date of the next coil to see how much time is spent loading another coil into the process.  So for example row 1's end date could say 2013-01-01 07:00:00.000 and row 2's start date is 2013-01-01 07:01:00.000. the result set I would be looking for in that specific row is 1.

I know I need to do something with joining the table on itself and adding to the row, but the syntax and logical thought process needed is alluding me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: mysql and sql server are different beasts,tag it correctly.

Comment: Once you've figured out which RDBMS you're using, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: And if SQL Server, which version is it?

Comment: sorry meant to tag it as sql management server studio not mysql

Comment: @McCee we're using sql server 2012 to host it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great news is that you're on SQL Server 2012, which introduced `LEAD()` and `LAG()` - making your task very easy.  `LEAD()` takes the current row and compares it to the next.  `LAG()` does the opposite.

Here's a quick example I put together:

```
create table #results (id int, startDate datetime, endDate datetime)

insert into #results
select  1, cast('10/1/2012' as datetime), cast('12/1/2012' as datetime)
insert into #results
select  1, cast('12/15/2012' as datetime), cast('12/31/2012' as datetime)
insert into #results
select  1, cast('2/1/2013' as datetime), cast('12/1/2013' as datetime)

select  id, startDate, endDate,
        DATEDIFF(day, endDate, LEAD(startDate) OVER (ORDER BY id)) DaysUntilNextCoil,
        DATEDIFF(day, startDate, LAG(endDate) OVER (ORDER BY id)) DaysSincePreviousCoil
from #results

drop table #results
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. Thanks, had no idea those existed.